# Install superset in ibm cloud IKS (ibm cloud k8s service)

Tags: apache-superset, iks

I want install superset follow this guide in ibm cloud IKS (ibm cloud k8s service):
https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/running-on-kubernetes#

but get Init:ImagePullBackOff error when pulling superset image:

Failed to pull image "apache/superset:dockerize": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/apache/superset:dockerize": no match for platform in manifest: not found

for ibm cloud IKS, I install ibm cloud cli and kubectl in my local window PC, so I manage k8s cluster from my local PC.

Answer (score 0):

same problem
solved by replacing default tag dockerize to: 7c2093c495505a43a737ba298634a8e853bfaf5f-dockerize-linux-amd64-3.9-slim-bookworm

Comment: the issue is gone, I did nothing, it is very strange, I assume it is superset product itself issue.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is gone, I did nothing, it is very strange, I assume it is superset product itself issue.